# Размещение сетки в виджетах PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgridlayout

Проблема заключается в следующем. У меня есть приложение на *PyQt5*. Использую сеточный макет для размещение элементов.

Прикрепил **2** виджета с кнопками на основную сетку. Есть функция `setSpacing`, которая устанавливает расстояние между виджетами, но мне для каждого виджета нужно использовать "свои" отступы (и размещать элементы так удобнее), поэтому внутри каждого виджета создал ещё по сетке.

С этого момента, при добавлении кнопок на сетку с помощью функции `addWidget(nameButton, coords)`, кнопки не устанавливаются на заданные координаты и функция `setSpacing` для сеток внутри каждого из виджетов отказывается работать.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы внутри каждой сетки нормально работали функции `addWidget` (элементы устанавливались на нужные координаты) и `setSpacing` (соблюдалось указанное расстояние между элементами).

Привожу схему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо, чтобы:

1. были соблюдены заданные мною отступы с помощью функции `setSpacing` и её производных (`setVerticalSpacing` и `setHorizontalSpacing`);
2. кнопка занимала указанные координаты на сетке `(row, column)`

Как это выглядит у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. функция `setSpacing` не даёт никакого результата (кнопки остаются на своих местах)
2. указанные координаты для размещения кнопок не соблюдаются (кнопки просто накладываются на сетку)

Привожу код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QGridLayout


class UiMainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralgrid = QGridLayout()
        self.centralgrid.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.right_widget()
        self.left_widget()

        self.main_frame_settings()

    # метод для создания левого виджета, а также для создания и размещения кнопок на нём
    def left_widget(self):
        self.buttongrid = QGridLayout()
        self.buttonswidget = QWidget(self)

        self.buttonswidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120, 120, 120)")

        self.btn_weather = QPushButton("Weather")
        self.btn_birth = QPushButton("Birthdays")
        
        # кнопки устанавливаются не в указанные координаты (14, 0) и (15, 0) !!!
        self.buttongrid.addWidget(self.btn_weather, 14, 0, 1, 1)
        self.buttongrid.addWidget(self.btn_birth, 15, 0, 1, 1)
        
        # функция не работает !!!
        self.buttongrid.setSpacing(25)

        self.buttonswidget.setLayout(self.buttongrid)
        self.centralgrid.addWidget(self.buttonswidget, 0, 0, 38, 1)

    # метод для создания правого виджета, а также для создания и размещения кнопок на нём
    def right_widget(self):
        self.gridWidget = QGridLayout()
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)

        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 160, 160)")

        # наложение сетки на основное окно
        self.setLayout(self.centralgrid)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.gridWidget)

        self.btn5 = QPushButton("QQ")
        self.btn6 = QPushButton("123")

        self.centralgrid.addWidget(self.centralwidget, 0, 1, 38, 5)
        # кнопки устанавливаются не в указанные координаты (0, 0) и (4, 0) !!!
        self.gridWidget.addWidget(self.btn5, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridWidget.addWidget(self.btn6, 4, 0, 1, 1)

    def main_frame_settings(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Lapa")
        self.resize(500, 500)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UiMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: покажите пожалуйста на изображении что вы хотите получить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понял как вы хотите разместить кнопки внутри левого и правого виджета.
Предложу вам поиграться с моим примером.

Обратите внимание, я размещаю в `centralgrid` виджеты `leftWidget` и `rightWidget`, а не `Layoutы`.

Рекомендую вам прочитать https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html ,
особое внимание обратите на `setColumnStretch`, `setRowStretch` и `setSpacing`.

Все работает как надо. Удачи вам.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralgrid = QGridLayout(self)                                 # +++ self
        self.centralgrid.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.left_widget()
        self.centralgrid.addWidget(self.leftWidget, 0, 0)   #, 38, 1)
        self.centralgrid.setColumnStretch(0, 2)                              # !!!  2
        
        self.right_widget()
        self.centralgrid.addWidget(self.rightWidget, 0, 1)  #, 38, 1)
        self.centralgrid.setColumnStretch(1, 9)                              # !!!  9

        self.main_frame_settings()

    # метод для создания левого виджета, а также для создания и размещения кнопок на нём
    def left_widget(self):
        self.leftWidget = QWidget()                                               # leftWidget
        self.leftWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120, 120, 120)") 
        self.leftGrid = QGridLayout(self.leftWidget)

        self.btn_weather = QPushButton("Weather")
        self.btn_birth = QPushButton("Birthdays")

        ''' или так
        spacer = QSpacerItem(25, 25, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.leftGrid.addItem(spacer, 0, 0)
        # кнопки устанавливается не в указанные координаты (14, 0) и (15, 0) !!!
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.btn_weather, 14, 0, 1, 1)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.btn_birth, 15, 0, 1, 1)
        self.leftGrid.addItem(spacer, 38, 0)  
        '''
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.btn_weather, 14, 1, 1, 1)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.btn_birth,   15, 1, 1, 1)
        
        self.leftGrid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)                        # !!!
        self.leftGrid.setColumnStretch(2, 1)                        # !!!
        self.leftGrid.setRowStretch(0, 1)                           # !!!
        self.leftGrid.setRowStretch(38, 1)                          # !!!
        
        # функция работает !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        self.leftGrid.setSpacing(25)

    # метод для создания правого виджета,
    def right_widget(self):
        self.rightWidget = QWidget()
        self.rightWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 160, 160)")

        self.btn5 = QPushButton("QQ")
        self.btn6 = QPushButton("123")
        
        self.rightGrid = QGridLayout(self.rightWidget)
        # кнопки устанавливается не в указанные координаты (0, 0) и (4, 0) !!!
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.btn5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.btn6, 4, 1, 1, 1)

#        self.rightGrid.setColumnStretch(0, 1)                        # !!!
#        self.rightGrid.setColumnStretch(2, 1)                        # !!!
        self.rightGrid.setRowStretch(0, 1)                            # !!!
        self.rightGrid.setRowStretch(38, 1)                           # !!!
        
        # функция работает !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        self.rightGrid.setSpacing(75)

    def main_frame_settings(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Lapa")
        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!